# MVC - Validating Property of External Class Using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am attempting to use data annotations in an MVC 2 web site to validate a model via a custom validation attribute (will call a controller action via ajax), however I am struggling to understand how to apply my proof of concept demo model to actual production code for the following reasons:

1. The model is a class from an external DLL which I have access to and can modify
2. Within the view the model is converter into a `Dictionary` object by the following code `var data = Model.ToDictionary();`

Specifically I do no know how to add the custom attribute to the DLL without having to hard code a reference to the controller/action I want the remote attribute to call, possible solutions I have come up with:

1. have the IsValid method call an interface that is implemented in the main project
2. Use a metadata class to apply the annotations at run time

Also I am not sure how converting the model to a dictionary will affect the built in MVC validation, will it still work "automagically" or will I need to develop some form of custom model binding?

Comment: Why are you using MVC 2?

Comment: Because that is what is used in the current environment, trust me I don't want to but am forced to